# Convirt Tool xen live migration virtualization

Tags: virtualization, xen, migration

have any one use http://convirture.com (convirt) tool to manage RHEL 5.3 XEN server and live migration if yes pls let me know how can done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Convirt forums ?
   What specific issue are you running in to ?
   Is the problem with migration happening with Linux or Windows VM ?
   try xm dmesg and look in to log files under  /var/log/xen

Jd

Comment: Hey Jd thanks u quick reply checking at forums what info there it dont work in fact one of the video at youtube.com that is also very bad in quality. If try do live migration guest system is get migrated but in shutdown status i thing that is not live migration if pls let me if you have try it will really help me lot bcoz already i have lost 2 server of production try convirt.